# Org-babel Common Lisp as HTML

Tags: org-export, org-babel

When exporting source code blocks in Org 8.2.10 to HTML, some programming languages (e.g. Java)  display the language name on hover, like so:

[image]

But for other languages (e.g. Common Lisp), no name displays on hover.

[image]

Is this expected behavior, or a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines in ox-html.el cause (among others) the hovering "Java" tag:

```
pre.src:hover:before { display: inline;}
pre.src-sh:before    { content: 'sh'; }
pre.src-bash:before  { content: 'sh'; }
pre.src-emacs-lisp:before { content: 'Emacs Lisp'; }
pre.src-R:before     { content: 'R'; }
pre.src-perl:before  { content: 'Perl'; }
pre.src-java:before  { content: 'Java'; }
pre.src-sql:before   { content: 'SQL'; }
```

Those are all languages defined, there is no "Lisp" or "Common Lisp".

When you test-add the line

```
pre.src-lisp:before {content: 'Common Lisp'; }
```

to the exported CSS file, you'll see a "Common Lisp" hover.

I wouldn't classify this as a bug, though you're right, a language name ought to be displayed for supported babel languages.

Comment: Thanks, I've filed a bug report, even though it's not a "bug" (more of an omission).